# Programmatically add content to static table view cell in IOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a static tableview on a storyboard, however can you add a content like a image,button,switch to a certain cell from code .

I have created an IB outlet for the relevant cell, do I have to add a view inside 1st ?

To more specific I have a switch in a cell and want to add customise it with RCSwitch, I don't see how you can add a RCSwitch to the storyboard, as all examples show the switch being created programmatically.

my code is this

```
RCSwitchOnOff* onSwitch = [[RCSwitchOnOff alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65, 23)];
[onSwitch setOn:YES];
[self.oneRow.contentView addSubview:onSwitch]; 
                   // onerow is the IBOutlet for the row within the tableview
```

Comment: What happens when you run your sample code?

Comment: the table row is blank

Comment: just created a new project and it works fine in this on

Answer (score 0):

How did you even create an IBOutlet for a single cell? The only thing you normally should be able to to if you want to personalize your cell in a xib is create a custom cell and use it programmatically in your cellForRow: atIndexPath:. However, I think the simplest solution here would be to do everything in code, as your app seems to be simple:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *yourCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

      if(!yourCell){
                yourCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
      }

      if(indexPath.row == yourDesiredCellIndexPath){
                // Do your thing
      }

      return yourCell;
}
```

Comment: to create a IBOutlet for a cell, just select the cell on the storyboard and ctrl and drag to .h to create the IBOutlet my file shows - @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *oneRow;